# Form with set of unique permission

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, custom-form, infopath-rules

How to create a form with unique permission access: Like If I want to submit a form to A team. Only A team should edit and rest all team should view or read. also, next time when I submit the form/ raised a question to B team, only B team should edit and rest all user group should have read option. Pls suggest me

Basically, my idea is I want a pop up like, before I submit a form it should ask abt giving different permission level to the different group. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box you don't have any feature to achieve this functionality in SharePoint forms. However you can easily do it by some custom javascripts and jquery.

Check JS script to validate the group being called in popup box and if the login user belongs to the group show the panel on the form or else hide it.

Comment: So there is no option to do this, am not getting JS script also. any alternative idea. like I can do something in permission level setting or adding a workflow so that the above conditions works ?

Comment: No , out of the box its not possible. You need to have custom codes on the form to achieve this functionality

Comment: Can u pls share me that code ?

Comment: its not one piece of functionality, You need to first call the text box where you will be entering Group name. Once you have the group name you need to assign permission to that item. Its not a very difficult task and basic knowledge on JavaScript and Jquery should do it. If I write, I have to create first a form and then create panels and text box accordingly whose attributes i will be referring in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In Library permissions you can create groups if you know the people that need to have read or write permission. Create a group A and give them contribute permission, then another group B with edit, and a visitor group with read.